# Moving Hbase region server to new host

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ambari, region

I am having 5 region servers in my cluster, I have added an additional 5 region servers,

can I directly decommission the older 5 region server with the help of ambari server, will it cause any data loss in HBase?

Using the Actions menu, click Selected Hosts > RegionServers > Decommission?

Answer (score 0):

Ambari's Decommission feature is mostly to silence alerting, in my experience while you do maintance.

HBase's data should remain [in HDFS](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#trouble.namenode.hbase.objects), but it wouldn't hurt to perform a backup.